# Is there possible to loop inside JavaScript object literal

Tags: javascript

So this is my question (maybe stupid), is there any possible to do this:

```
 var data {
     "label" : value,
     "sets" : [             
         for (var i=0; i < item.length; i++)
         {
             somedata: "data"   
         }
     ]  
 }
```

to reach result:

```
 var data {
     "label" : value,
     "sets" : [  
         {
            somedata: "data1"
         },
         {
            somedata: "data2"
         }
     ]  
 }
```

Much thx for help.

Comment: No. JSON contains data, not code.

Comment: No. That's not possible.

Comment: The exact result you want is really unclear.

Comment: I must say it's a nice abstract idea.

Comment: Why isn't it possible to loop when you *create* the object?

Comment: Can you confirm you don't really mean JSON (that is a string used for data exchange) but a literal object ? *"JSON object"* has no meaning.

Comment: @dystroy The words I like to use are "JavaScript object" or "JSON string" when I want to be extremely clear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [jimm101 has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307814/227299), you are not working with JSON, that's just JavaScript (the `var` in there proves it) . If you want to calculate a value inside a literal JavaScript object, you can use an immediately invoked function

```
var data = {
     "label" : value,
     "sets" : (function(){
         var arr = [];
         for (var i=0; i < item.length; i++) {
             arr.push( {somedata: "data" + i} ) ;
         }
         return arr;
      })()
 };
```

As [dystroy has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25307730/227299) You can also use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return a transformed array, without needing an immediately invoked function, which looks a little nicer

Answer (score 1):

You may use functional programming :

```
var data = {
  "label" : "value",
  "sets" : item.map(function(_,i){ return {somedata: "data"+(i+1)} })  
}
```

Comment: This is not JSON, but if OP's goal is actually to create a JavaScript object, then this will work.

Comment: There's no JSON in OP's question

Comment: The question's title is "Is there possible to loop inside JSON object".

Comment: @Khalid JSON is a data exchange format, a serialization of plain objects in any language. We can create that JSON in C#, Java, or any other language

Comment: @JuanMendes is there a loop in json ?

Comment: @JuanMendes There's nothing that can be called "JSON object", obviously OP isn't using the right term

Comment: @dystroy My comment is just because I don't quite understand what Khalid means by "JSON is just notation". If by notation, he means a data exchange format, then he's correct. I was just pointing out that any language can generate JSON, JavaScript is **a** solution, not **the** solution

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
var data = {
    label: value,
    get sets(){
        var array = [];
        /* write your logic to fill the array here. */
        return array;
    }
}
```

Reference [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get)

Comment: This builds the array each time the value is read, which make it improper for almost any use

Comment: And this is not JSON either.

Answer (score 1):

As others have commented, JSON is data, not code.  It looks like you're making javascript code though, since JSON also wouldn't include the `var data` part.

- JSON => JavaScript Object Notation, a wide-spread way of representing data.
- javascsript object => A structure within the javascript programming language that uses JavaScript Object Notation.

You can do something like this.

```
var data = {
    "label" : 'my_label',
};

item = ['one','two','another'];
data.sets = [];
for (var i=0; i < item.length; i++)
{
    data.sets.push({'somedata': item[i]});
}
```

Comment: Good point, the OP has a `var`  in there, so it's not JSON but I think the OP wants something inline? Also, "javascsript object => A structure within the javascript programming language that **may** use JavaScript Object Notation." JavaScript objects do not fully conform to JSON, no need to quote properties, and you can use single quotes.

Comment: @JuanMendes good point ... I was tempted to hedge with "looks like JSON" or "may be JSON" but that's almost flamebaiting on stackoverflow ... :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array comprehension (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Array_comprehensions), but it's not supported yet by all browsers (ECMAScript 6).

```
var value = "test";
var item = ["data1", "data2", "data3"];

var data = {
    "label" : value,
    "sets" : [for (x of item) {somedata: x}]
};

/*
    Result : 

    data = {
        "label":"test",
        "sets":[
            {"somedata":"data1"},
            {"somedata":"data2"},
            {"somedata":"data3"}
        ]
    }
*/
```

Answer (score -4):

You can have nested data in JSON like for example

```
var myObject = {
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Doe",
  "age": 39,
  "sex": "M",
  "salary": 70000,
  "registered": true,
  "interests": [ "Reading", "Mountain Biking", "Hacking" ],
  "favorites": {
    "color": "Blue",
    "sport": "Soccer",
    "food": "Spaghetti"
  }, 
  "skills": [
    {
      "category": "JavaScript",
      "tests": [
        { "name": "One", "score": 90 },
        { "name": "Two", "score": 96 }
      ] 
    },
    {
      "category": "CouchDB",
      "tests": [
        { "name": "One", "score": 79 },
        { "name": "Two", "score": 84 }
      ] 
    },
    {
      "category": "Node.js",
      "tests": [
        { "name": "One", "score": 97 },
        { "name": "Two", "score": 93 }
      ] 
    }
  ]
};
```

You can access such an array and its contents using a loop in your program

Source: http://www.json.com/

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with OP's question.

Comment: I answered wrt to accessing the data using a loop... i guess its not what the owner is looking for

Comment: If you look at the examples, it's clear that OP is trying to produce the data with a loop, not access it.